# Left join but take random values

Tags: mysql, sql

Just learning SQL. How do I take random samples after joining two tables? Thanks a lot.

```
select  *
from t1 
left join t2  on t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: Which version of ``MySQL`` are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `ORDER BY rand()` and `LIMIT` with sample size (for example 5):

```
select  *
from t1 
left join t2  on t1.ID = t2.ID
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I tried that, but it did not work! It says expected something between "(" and ")".

Comment: I think you need order by uuid() instead of order by rand()

Comment: if you put something there (f.e. ``rand(1)``) it will use the same random seed (and therefore return the same results on every run). Of course you can change the seed manually

Comment: I transposed newid() in T-SQL to uuid()  but you're right, uuid() is sequential so won't help, rand() works for for me in mysql.  It doesn't work in MSSQL because it's calculated per transaction not per record.

Comment: suprisingly, ``uuid()`` returns a new set of values (but with the same order) each execution

Comment: I did. I included a number and now it says expected something between "(" and number.

Comment: Just to close this look. I think it may have to do with the Teradata implementation of sql. The other option I am thinking of now is generating a column populated with random values and sorting based on it. Thank you for your help tho.